# Updating ArrayCollection item without memory reference

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

**Introduction:**
As the question states, I want to update an item in different ArrayCollections throughout my application if the given item is represented in different places/ArrayCollection's.

This would be straightforward if I could use the ArrayCollection.*updateItem* or *getItemIndex*, which as far as i understand uses memory reference to find the item. My problem is that when the user saves an item I retrieve an updated object from the database, which causes the memory lookup to fail in finding a match.

My current approach is either looping through the ArrayCollection(*ac*) to find the item if i dont have any index of the updated object or using *ac.setItemAt(item, index)* if i have.

My objects/items do implement the *IUID* property which i was hoping would provide a efficient way to perfom my task, but i still haven't found any good solutions on the web.

**Question**:
This question is a more general question, because i can perform the task my using the approach described earlier, but it seems kinda cumbersome and not very efficient, which leads me to my question. How do you perform this task in your application? Do i have to relie on my current approach, or are there better more effeicient ways to performing this task?

Comment: i dont really understand what does you mean

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well in short and simplified, I have several ArrayCollection's in my application, which i often use as dataProviders to various DataGrids. The same object may be present in more than one of these ArrayCollection's. So when the user input results in the object beeing modified/changed in one ArrayCollection, I need to check/update the same object in the other ArrayCollections, if the same object is present in more than one ArrayCollection

Comment: okay you can use the same object reference in all array collections and once you get the updated object instead of replacing the object just change the properties of the existing object with the newly gained object properties. Hope this will help

Comment: if you are not happy with the suggestion, i have to see your code then  others or myself can help you out

Comment: Thanks for the input. This may work in some of my cases, but there are still some places where the "same" object is retrieved by two different queries to the database. Like one datagrid containing the users taks, and another datagrid containing all the current tasks. These datagrids are filled through different queries to the database, and may contain the same object. I guess i might have done this in a different way, still i was hoping i didnt have too :)

Comment: Dont get me wrong, i do like your suggestion, but as i posted in the new comment, there are some places where this "isnt possible", since the "same object"/database row is retrieved from the database through two different queries as described above. These objects will have the same uid, but not the same memory reference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8826/discussion-between-rajesh-adhi-and-sebastian)